# Problem using opencv-python on my mac (OS version==10.11, El Capitan)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, module, package, opencv, python

### Actually whenever I try to import cv2 in my code it shows the following
error:

File "/Users/mac/Desktop/projectprograme.krx/python_projects/opencv.py", line 1, in 
import cv2
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/project_dom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 5, in 
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/project_dom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/project_dom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.51.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /opt/anaconda3/envs/project_dom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.51.100.dylib

---

Can somebody have the solution for the problem? The problem is because of OS version, python version or anything else

Comment: Please some more info about the context and what you're trying to do.

Comment: How did you install Python and OpenCV? Are they compatible versions?

Comment: I installed python from it's official website and opencv==4.3.0.36 from pip3

Comment: i'm trying to open video using my laptop camera but whenever i try to import cv2, there shows errors